# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{1}{\tan^{-1}(x)\, dx}$ via a series (not IBP)

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, summation

I tried :

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_{0}^{1}{\tan^{-1}(x)\, dx}\\&=\int_{0}^{1}{\sum_{k\geq0}{\frac{(-1)^kx^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}\, dx}\\&=\sum_{k\geq0}{\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\left[\frac{x^{2(k+1)}}{2(k+1)}\right]_{0}^{1}}\\&=\sum_{k\geq0}{\frac{(-1)^k}{2(2k+1)(k+1)}}
\end{align}$$
I'm not sure how to continue though, the last line should be equal to $1/4(\pi-\ln4)$ in the end.

Comment: Not quite what you’re after, but [worth thinking about](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions#/media/File%3AFunktionUmkehrIntegral2.svg).

Comment: @Integrand dude, people like to do abnormal things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** The factor $$\frac{1}{2 (2 k + 1) (k + 1)}$$ is rational in $k$, which suggests decomposing using the method of partial fractions, then evaluating the series separately for (the product of $(-1)^k$ and) each summand.

> $$\frac{1}{(2 k + 1) (k + 1)} = \frac{2}{2 k + 1} - \frac{1}{k + 1} .$$

Answer (score 1):

Using partial fraction decompisition
$$\begin{align} \frac 1{(2k+1)(k+1)}&=\frac A{2k+1}+\frac B{k+1}\\1&=A(k+1)+B(2k+1)=k(A+2B)+A+B \end{align}$$$$\\\begin{cases}A+2B=0\\A+B=1\end{cases}\\B=-1\\A=2$$
So
$$I=\underbrace{\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}}_{S_1}-\frac12\underbrace{\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+1}}_{S_2}$$
Recall that
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{k\ge0}x^k ,\lvert x\rvert<1 $$
Therefore
$$\begin{align}f(x)&=\frac{1}{1+x^2}=\frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^kx^{2k},\lvert x\rvert< 1\\\int_0^tf(x)dx&=\arctan(t)=\int_0^t\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^kx^{2k}dx=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^k\int_0^t x^{2k}dx=\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(-1)^kt^{2k+1}}{2k+1},\end{align}$$Now let$$\begin{align}g(x)&=\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1}{1-(-x)}=\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^kx^k\\ \int_0^t g(x)dx&=\log(1+t)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^kt^{k+1}}{k+1}\end{align}$$The Alternating series test states that a sum $\sum_{k\ge 0}(-1)^ka_k$ converges if $$\lvert a_{k+1}\rvert\le \lvert a_k\rvert$$and $$\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k=0$$ It is then easy to see that the above series of $\arctan(t)$ converges at $t=1$ which is  exactly $S_1$ and the series $\log(1+t)$ converges at $t=1$ which is exactly $S_2$, so $$\begin{align}S_1&=\arctan(1)=\frac\pi 4\\S_2&=\log(2)\end{align}$$Then Finally$$I=\frac\pi 4-\frac12\log(2)=\frac\pi4-\frac14\log(4)=\frac14(\pi-\log(4))$$

Answer (score 0):

**Feynman’s trick**

Let’s consider the parametrised integral
$$
I(a)=\int_0^1 \tan ^{-1}(a x) d x
$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+a^2 x^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2 a^2}\left[\ln \left(1+a^2 x^2\right)\right]_0^1 \\
& =\frac{1}{2 a^2} \ln \left(1+a^2\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Integrating $I’(a)$ from $a=0$ to $1$ brings us
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \tan ^{-1}(x) d x& =I(1)-I(0) \\
& =\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+a^2\right)}{2 a^2} d a \\&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ {n-1}}{n} \int_0^1 a^{2 n-2} d a\\&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n(2 n-1)}\\&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ {n-1}}{2 n-1}-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^ {n-1}}{n}\\
& =\frac{1}{4}(\pi-\ln 4)
\end{aligned}
$$